# Sending two different requests to same PHP script in Java

Tags: java, php, https, outputstream, illegalstateexception

I am trying to make a Java application that communicates with a PHP script I have online! My application makes one request to receive some data, then processes it and makes another request to the script. However, the second request does not work at all, even though I `close()` the `OutputStreamWriter`, the `BufferedReader` and the `HttpsUrlConnection` for the first request!

I know it's not the request that it is not working because I send it  before anything else, it works! And I also know that the method with the second request in is running. Here is the basics of what I have at the minute:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("https://mysite.com/script.php");
    HttpsUrlConnection conn = (HttpsUrlConnection) url.openConnection()
    conn.setDoInput(true); conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String request = URLEncoder.encode("request_type", "UTF-8) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("first", "UTF-8);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(request);
    writer.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String response;

    while((response = in.readLine()) != null){
         if(response.equals("firstresponse")){
             in.close(); writer.close();
             conn.disconnect();
             makeSecondRequest();}
    }
}catch(Exception e){}

public void makeSecondRequest(){
    URL url = new URL("https://mysite.com/script.php");
    HttpsUrlConnection conn = (HttpsUrlConnection) url.openConnection()
    conn.setDoInput(true); conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String request = URLEncoder.encode("request_type", "UTF-8) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("second", "UTF-8);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(request);
    writer.flush();
}
```

So, if anyone knows how this SHOULD be done/why it may not be working I would be grateful if you could tell me as soon as possible...

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
I have now added `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` statement in the `makeSecondRequest()` part of *my* code and I receive the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:909)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setDoOutput(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:454)
    at engines.LicenceManagement.sendFingerprint(LicenceManagement.java:193)
    at engines.LicenceManagement.verifyOnline(LicenceManagement.java:147)
    at engines.LicenceManagement.actionPerformed(LicenceManagement.java:541)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: The empty catch block will hide any exceptions that get thrown in your code block.  I'd recommend getting rid of it, or at least doing something with the caught exception in the catch block, even if it's only rethrowing it. If an exception is being thrown in this code then knowing that it is would make your life in figuring out the problem far easier!

Comment: Yes , I suppose you're right - it is a bit silly of me not to print any stack traces! Unfortunately I havent got access to MY computer until tommorrow afternoon, but I will look at any exceptions and report back ASAP...

Comment: @GordonM: Okay, I've added `e.printStackTrace` in my second catch block! See my original post for details... Does anybody have a better idea of what may be wrong now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me why because I have no idea, but, I put the second method practically as it was into another class and what do you know, no errors!

I'm not going to investigate as to why at the minute because I want to get my software finished as soon as possible, but if anybody wants to enlighten me on the subject be my guest - I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never call the [connect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) method. In the first request the connect method is called by the getInputStream() method. So to fix your problem it should be enough to add conn.connect() to your makeSecondRequest method.

Comment: Unfortunately not! I added that line in my second method but it made no difference to the exception whatsoever... Still, thanks for the answer.